# join multiple subqueries wtih aggregated data

Tags: postgresql

My data are:

```
order_id    chef_name   order_returned
1001    Charles McBakey Y
1001    Sarah McCookin  N
1001    John McFry  N
1001    Charles McBakey N
1001    John McFry  N
1001    John McFry  Y
1001    John McFry  Y
1001    Sarah McCookin  N
1001    Charles McBakey N
1001    Sarah McCookin  N
1001    Charles McBakey Y
1001    Charles McBakey N
1001    Sarah McCookin  N
1001    John McFry  N
1001    Sarah McCookin  N
1001    Charles McBakey Y
1001    John McFry  N
1001    Sarah McCookin  Y
1001    John McFry  Y 


select chef_name, count(chef_name) as cnt_total
from order_returns t
group by chef_name
```

when I used code above, I got the table below:

```
"chef_name" "cnt_total"
"Sarah McCookin"    6
"Charles McBakey"   6
"John McFry"    7
```

Then I used code below

```
select chef_name, count(chef_name) as cnt_y
from order_returns 
where order_returned = 'Y'
group by chef_name
```

got this table:

```
"chef_name" "cnt_y"
"Charles McBakey"   3
"John McFry"    3
"Sarah McCookin"    1
```

then I used code below:

```
select chef_name,count(chef_name) as cnt_n
from orders
where order_returned = 'N'
group by chef_name
```

I got this table

```
"chef_name" "cnt_n"
"Charles McBakey"   3
"John McFry"    4
"Sarah McCookin"    5
```

then I combined these three tables using following codes:

```
select chef_name, count(chef_name) as cnt_total
from order_returns t
group by chef_name
join
(select chef_name, count(chef_name) as cnt_y
from order_returns 
where order_returned = 'Y'
group by chef_name) y
on t.chef_name = y.chef_name
join
(select chef_name,count(chef_name) as cnt_n
from order_returns
where order_returned = 'N'
group by chef_name) n
on y.chef_name = n.chef_name
```

I got the error message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"
LINE 4: join.

Could you anyone help me this out?

Thanks,

Comment: Some data to work with would be nice. `distinct` is completely nonsense, it doesn't do anything in your queries. Never use distinct, unless you really really need it. And that's unlikely.

Comment: In my case, I don't need to use distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've nearly got it.

You just need to properly isolate the first sub-query as a sub-query in the same way you've done the second and third:

```
select * from 
(select chef_name, count(chef_name) as cnt_total
from order_returns 
group by chef_name) t
join
(select chef_name, count(chef_name) as cnt_y
from order_returns 
where order_returned = 'Y'
group by chef_name) y
on t.chef_name = y.chef_name
join
(select chef_name,count(chef_name) as cnt_n
from order_returns
where order_returned = 'N'
group by chef_name) n
on y.chef_name = n.chef_name
```

I've just used `select *` - once you've got the syntax error sorted you'll probably want to specify specific fields

`select t.chef_name, t.cnt_total, y.cnt_y, n.cnt_n from` ...

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand it why mine didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your description implies that you are attempting to get the counts for total orders, returned orders, and non-returned orders by chef_name. You do not need to `union` 3 queries; it can be done in a single query with a **single** select. You accomplish this with the [aggregate function filter clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html), in this case `count(*)`:  (See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/asvihcXk))

```
select chef_name
     , count(*)                                      cnt_total
     , count(*) filter (where order_returned = 'Y')  cny_y
     , count(*) filter (where order_returned = 'N')  cnt_n 
  from order_returns
 group by chef_name;
```

Comment: THANKS. IT IS SO SIMPLE. I DON'T KNOW THE FILTER FUNCTION IN POSTGRESQL.

Comment: If the above answered your question then you should accept it. This helps others later having the same or closely related questions. It also removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.